# Make calculations in csv with php

Tags: php, csv

First let me introduce myself:
Im 33. 'Living in the Netherlands and i'm a newbe if it comes to php :)

I have a csv file on my vps httpdocs\data\1day.csv . In this file there are two columns: datetime and value. The file looks like this:

```
"datetime","value",
"2016-01-02 10:50:01","1060.9",
"2016-01-02 10:45:01","1060.6",
```

I want to make a simple calculation to the file 1day.csv and save it to another csv file. Let's say the caluclation will be value * 5:

```
"datetime","value","value2",
"2016-01-02 10:50:01","1060.9","5304.5",
"2016-01-02 10:45:01","1060.9","5304.5",
```

The calculation needs to be done over the whole "value" column.

I want to do this with php and let a cronjob execute this script every x minutes.

Can anybody help me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) SO is **not a free coding service** What have you tried to do for yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would maybe do it more simple. If you didn't know how many columns you could do the extra loops to get column names, but it does not look necessary.

```
$output = "datetime, value1, value2\n"; // Column names
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
  $output .='"' . $row[0] . '" ,';
  $output .='"' . $row[1] . '" ,';
  $output .='"' . ($row[1] * 5) . '"';
  $output .="\n";
}
```

Comment: Dear @stubben, Thanks for your answer. When i use your code i get (first row): ````datetime, value1, value2"2016-01-03 00:40:02" ,"" ,"0"```` and all orher rows are: ````"2016-01-03 00:35:01" ,"" ,"0"````

Comment: 1st oh :-), `$output = "datetime, value1, value2\n"; ` 2nd oh... mysql_fetch_array (if you use mysql_fetch_assoc http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php it would work). Use `$row[0]` for first value, `$row[1]` for second. Sorry, but I did not test :-( I've updated my example.

Comment: Dear @stubben, Your updated example worked perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

@riggsfolly

Ok. This is what i got so far:

```
// Database Connection

$host="localhost";
$uname="xxxxx";
$pass="xxxxx";
$database = "xxxxx"; 

$connection=mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pass); 

echo mysql_error();

//or die("Database Connection Failed");
$selectdb=mysql_select_db($database) or 
die("Database could not be selected"); 
$result=mysql_select_db($database)
or die("database cannot be selected <br>");

// Fetch Record from Database

$output = "";
$table = "quotes"; // Enter Your Table Name 
$sql = mysql_query("select datetime, value from $table where type = '5' order by datetime desc limit 333");
$columns_total = mysql_num_fields($sql);

// Get The Field Name

for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$heading = mysql_field_name($sql, $i);
$output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output .="\n";

// Get Records from the table

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
}
$output .="\n";
}

// Save the file

$directory = "/var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/data/";
$filename = "1day.csv";
$fd = fopen ("$directory" . $filename, "w");
fputs($fd, $output);
fclose($fd);
exit;
```

The part where i get stuck is to add the extra column with the calculated value.